# Check if html tag is self-closing - HTMLparser - Python

Tags: python, html, parsing, tags

Is there a way to check if a tag is a self-closing tag with HTMLparser?

I know self-closing tags are handled by the built-in function: `handle_startendtag()`

However, it only handles them if they are explicitely closed..eg `<img src="x.jpg"/>`

and not: `<img src="x.jpg">`

I am making a program that takes an html file and spits out a sass template.

I want to close these img tags in the output file that are not explicitly closed in the html file.

Cheers

Answer (score 3):

Not exactly a Python-specific solution, but if you want to know *which* tags have this "self-closing property", you can look at the official HTML5 specs: these are formally known as *[void elements](http://www.w3.org/html/wg/drafts/html/master/single-page.html#void-elements)*.

```
area, base, br, col, embed, hr, img, input, keygen, link, menuitem,
meta, param, source, track, wbr
```

Strictly speaking, void elements do not have closing tags at all, but [permit an extra `/` immediately before the `>`](http://dev.w3.org/html5/spec-author-view/syntax.html#syntax-start-tag).

Answer (score 0):

Simple solution is to use BeautifulSoup.

```
In [76]: from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

In [77]: BeautifulSoup('<img src="x.jpg">')
Out[77]: <img src="x.jpg"/>
```

You can also check if a tag is self closing or not.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from bs4.element import Tag

soup = BeautifulSoup(html)
tags = [tag for tag in soup if isinstacne(tag, Tag)
self_closing = [tag for tag in tags if tag.isSelfClosing]
```

Every `Tag` element has `isSelfClosing` property. So, you can filter them out.